# Why Docker COPY works differently with single file and directory?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-image

I have a front end project which includes `package.json` inside it.(imagine `create-react-app` for example)

When I run below command everything works fine with no error.

`first DockerFile`

```
COPY . develop
WORKDIR develop
```

But in case I want `COPY`, `package.json` next command I will face an error.

`second DockerFile`

```
COPY package.json develop
WORKDIR develop
```

error message: `Cannot mkdir: /develop is not a directory`

I know how to dockerize my project with the below command.

```
WORKDIR develop
COPY package.json .
```

I am just curious to know why the first Dockerfile works and the second one won't work.

I also used `RUN ls` after `COPY` command and find out in both case the `develop` directory has been generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because `COPY package.json develop` is instructed to copy the packages.json to the container as **develop**. So the next directive WORKDIR fails because **develop** is not a directory but a file.

Use the **/** before && after ***develop*** and it should work.

```
FROM alpine
COPY temp.txt /develop/
WORKDIR develop
```

Comment: adding `/` only before `develop` didn't help, but adding `/` before and after of `develop` worked just like the code you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks. Updated the comment.